# Using Web worker for Image caching in FIrefox

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, caching, web-worker

it's me again with a fairly specific question. I am trying to use a **webworker** to **cache a lot of images**, which I am going to use **THREE.js** scene within an *externally loaded AngularJS* application. I am bound to use Firefox Nightly (59) due to its most performant WebVR implementation.

For the THREE.js 3D scene I am going to present, I have to preload a lot of panorama Image Tiles. On first page load, I want to cache (persistent, client side) an upper bound of ~4 million (30000 possible panorama spheres * 32 tiles per sphere * 4 resolutions) images for all adjacent panoramas (sizes ranging from 1kb to 200kb). For those amounts of

THREE.js (I am bound to r74) caches Images in a temporary Object (Image/Fileloader.Cache), but they are lost on browser refresh. Also I have no control over the loaders logic, as the AngularJS/THREE App is loaded from an external company. I only want to cache the Images *once* and keep them cached until I manually delete the cache. So every call of their Textureloader and Imageloader should create a cache hit. **This is why i have to solve this on Browser/HTTP level, not application logic.**

so basically what I'm doing is something like this:

some appropriate place in an AngularJS service:

```
if($window.Worker){
  var urls = [...] // array with url strings
  this.cacheWorker = new Worker('scripts/workers/cacheWorker.js');
  this.cacheWorker.onmessage = this.onCacheWorkerMessage;

  this.cacheWorker.postMessage(urls)
}
```

cacheWorker.js:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  var cacheName = 'default_cache'         
  var urls = e.data.urls;

  if('caches' in self){
    caches.open(this.cacheName).then((cache) => {

    for (let u = 0; u < urls.length; u++) {
      var url = urls[u];
      const request = new Request(url, { mode: 'no-cors' }); // cross-origin hack
      fetch(request).then(response => {
        cache.put(request, response);
      });        
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Looks fine, should work, what happened?**

After cacheing an Image, trying to load the exact same Image with the ImageLoader doesnt give me a cache hit *in Firefox*, in Chrome, *it hits*.

Looking at the Request headers, *Origin* is the same string for both. *Same port, same domain, same protocol*... **is it a Problem that the referrer is the path of my worker script?**

**Maybe the cache is too small?** first off, in *about:config* I changed the following:

- browser.cache.disk.max_entry_size: -1
- browser.cache.memory.max_entry_size: -1
- browser.cache.disk.capacity:
  I can not change this, **it always gets revertet to 358400?**. I have No User prefs file so you understand why only this value gets reverted?
- browser.cache.offline.capacity: 10000000

**Maybe a serviceworker a better solution for this?**

Please help me out, I need some input!